# How to skip kernel update?

Tags: kernel, updates

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i686 on VirtulBox. Every time I check the updates, there's a new Linux kernel. If I install the new kernel, I have to install the Virtulbox Guest Additions again and reboot the server. I don't want to do this every week. I know I can manually uncheck the kernel packages from update manager, but is there a way to skip the kernel update automatically? I found an answer here, but it's for Ubuntu 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

APT (Advanced Packaging Tool) is the system that Ubuntu uses to manage all of the software installed on a system. It allows you to “pin” a package to a certain version, so that it won’t be updated when you the Update Manager runs.

To pin your kernel packages, first you must determine what version your kernel is. One way to do this is to open the Synaptic Package Manager in System > Administration.

[image]

Type in “linux-generic” in the Quick search text field and hit enter.

[image]

Make a note of the number listed in the “Installed Version” column. We’ll use it in the next step.

Next, we need to edit the file /etc/apt/preferences. Open it by pressing Alt+F2 to bring up the Run Application window and entering in:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences
```

[image]

This will open up a gedit window. Most likely the window will be blank, unless you’ve played around with APT before.

In the window, type in the following, replacing the version number with the version number you found in the Synaptic Package Manager.

```
Package: linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-restricted-modules-generic
Pin: version <insert version here>
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

[image]

Save the file and close gedit. If you open the Update Manager, you should see that the Linux kernel updates are now hidden!

[image]

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10606/how-to-hide-kernel-updates-in-ubuntu/)

## Blocking packages with APT/DPKG

Remember the package name of your kernel from above.

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo -s
```

And hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Enter your password for sudo:

```
echo kernel_package_name hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

Replace `kernel_package_name` with the name of the kernel you want to pin.

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

## To remove pin from Apt/Dpkg:

Open a terminal

```
sudo -s
echo kernel_package install | dpkg --set-selections
```

Replace kernel_package with the package you want to pin.

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)

What you're trying to do is called pinning. The sources I gave you above, have the essentials on what you must do to accomplish your tasks in hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that we are using different version. I don't have Synaptic Package Manager and /etc/apt/preferences on my Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Yes, Synaptic is no longer installed by default.

Comment: @garconcn, you can install Synaptic and install the fix i told you, or read the question again, as i have put more info on it

Comment: @LnxSlck, I installed Synaptic and followed your instruction. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In one line it is:

```
echo $(dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep image | awk '{print $2}') hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

This will set kernel's image state from *install* to *hold* and thus will prevent updates.

Answer (score 8):

The one-liner by Christoph doesn't take the extra package into account (e.g. linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic). Rather use this one:

```
for i in $(dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep image | awk '{print $2}'); do echo $i hold | dpkg --set-selections; done
```

Answer (score 4):

In relation superlexx's suggestion: that line will miss the "headers" package:

```
dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep image | awk '{print $2}'
linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic
```

So how about simply using the following:

```
dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep kernel | awk '{print $2}'
linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic
```

Comment: If the extras/headers/etc packages are not marked, are there issues? Or, are you suggesting marking them as well for completeness? I'd expect that Ubuntu would not attempt to install an updated headers package, until the linux-image was installed (headers being a dependency of image). I have yet to verify this.

Comment: You guys could collaborate on a single one-liner instead of stacking 3 anwsers one on another. =P Just sayin

Comment: It's unnecesary to invoke grep if you're already using awk: `dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*"  | awk '/kernel/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

This purges meta kernel packages that enable kernel updates:

```
sudo apt purge $(apt-cache rdepends -i --installed linux-{headers,image}-$(uname -r)|awk '!/[0-9]/ && /^[ ]/{print $1}')
```

(If you have just upgraded kernel, you have to reboot first with the new kernel, or find the latest kernel release and use it in above instead of "$(uname -r)".)

It is recommended to install kernels updates though since they are mostly security updates.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04.1, the following code works

```
for i in $(dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep image | awk '{print $2}'); do echo $i hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections; done
```

the is an improvement of Superlexx's code, the `sudo` is added

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

You will find:

> **hi**  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic ...
>
> **hi**  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic ...

note that the tag now reads `hi`, not `ii`

to remove pin

```
for i in $(dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep image | awk '{print $2}'); do echo $i install | sudo dpkg --set-selections; done
```

Comment: Nice answer but you put `sudo` in the commentary not the command...

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version: (Replace "hold" with "install" to remove pin)

```
 dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep kernel | awk '{print $2,"hold"}' | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

To see the state of all kernel images and headers, run:

```
 dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-"
```