# Is there any method to have the Update Manager ignore kernel versions older than the one currently installed?

Tags: kernel, update-manager

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 and recently installed kernel 2.6.38-generic-pae (version 2.6.38-15.66~lucid1), which works just fine. There is one small nuisance, however: The Update Manager continues to ask me to install new 2.6.32 kernel versions.

Is there any method to have the Update Manager ignore  kernel versions older than the one currently installed?

Answer (score 1):

Pinning may be the answer: [How to skip kernel update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178324/how-to-skip-kernel-update?rq=1)
I'd still appreciate any other suggestions.

The trouble is that I cannot get pinning to work. The Update Manager is still offering to install 2.6.32-x kernel versions, even when I "lock" my version 2.6.38 using Synaptic. Suggestions?