# Workaround to re-install guest additions after every kernel update

Tags: updates, virtualbox, guest-additions

I have a working VM with ubuntu under virtual box. Everything works fine, but there's a detail that's getting on my nerves.

Every time i receive a kernel update, i have to re-install virtual box's guest additions. Is there a way to automate this besides skipping the update ([i found information on that approach here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178324/how-to-skip-kernel-update) ). Is there  a way to keep up with kernel updates without reinstalling the guest additions every time?

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting the [VirtualBox User Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11306688):

> Be sure to install DKMS before installing the Linux Guest Additions.
>   If DKMS is not available or not installed, the guest kernel modules
>   will need to be recreated manually whenever the guest kernel is
>   updated using the command
>
> /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup as root.

[...]

> If it is not installed, use this command for Ubuntu/Debian systems:
>
> sudo apt-get install dkms

Comment: I LOVE YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to manage your Virtualbox VMs, you can install the [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/blob/master/Readme.md) plugin to automatically detect out-of-date guest additions and update them.