# How do I "unpin" the kernel?

Tags: kernel

Earlier this year I had to pin my kernel because an update came down the pipe that broke WINE compatibility with Win16 apps.  I followed the directions here:
[How to skip kernel update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178324/how-to-skip-kernel-update)

It appears as though the issue has been fixed because tests have shown that Win16 applications once again work with later kernel builds.  I've removed the changes I made, but the kernel is still not updating.  What am I missing?

Comment: what exactly have you done to remove the changes you made?

Comment: Well, the directions I linked indicated adding those lines to a file that was initially empty, so all I did was just delete those lines.

Comment: hmm.. have you rebooted?

Comment: From the question you linked : "To remove pin from Apt/Dpkg:

Open a terminal

sudo -s
echo kernel_package install | dpkg --set-selections
Replace kernel_package with the package you want to pin.

Now run:

sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get upgrade" so you need to run those commands

Comment: @bodhi.zazen he probably edited the /etc/apt/preferences file too.... he has to reset that file aswell.

Comment: Possible, we really do not have sufficient information.

Comment: Guys, I SAID I edited /etc/apt/preferences and REMOVED the lines I'd added.  The system has also been rebooted several times and I'd already done a "sudo apt-get update" when I installed a new package from a new PPA.  However, I did not do a "sudo apt-get upgrade" so I guess I'll give that a try tonight and let you know how it goes.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, I ran the "sudo apt-get upgrade" and all it did was update the version of Unity I was running.  The kernel still wasn't touched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, TONS and TONS of hits on how to pin a kernel, but not one blessed article I can find on the entire internet on how to "unpin" the kernel and let allow it to be updated again?  That's just INSANE.

In any event, I never did find out how to "unpin" the kernel, BUT I went to this link: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kernel/

And I pulled down the latest AMD64 kernel, headers and extras for Trusty and just installed them manually and rebooted.  I'm finally on a later kernel, and since I am no longer on the "pinned" kernel, I think it should upgrade normally from now on.

Comment: Check this solution for unholding a kernel: https://askubuntu.com/a/336687/356228