# Freeze Kernel and Xorg versions at 14.04.2 to keep the fglrx drivers working

Tags: 14.04, kernel, xorg, fglrx

Since ATI is no longer supporting `fglrx` drivers for my multiple ATI Radeon HD 6870 video cards running in tandem after version 14.04.2, I need to hold version 14.04.2 with no updates to the kernel or to xorg for the foreseeable future. I still want to perform updates & upgrades to non-related packages.

I know that I can hold the kernel at the current version with the following command:

```
echo linux-image-generic-lts-utopic hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

in order to the 'ii' to 'hi' and prevent an update with dpkg.

My two questions are, with this be a sufficient method to lock down the kernel, and how can I do the same thing and lock down the current xorg drivers as follows?

```
echo xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

**EDIT:**

So that's what I did...
Fresh 14.04.2 Install & put holds on the following:

```
echo linux-image-generic-lts-utopic hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections

echo xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

and for good measure I also included...

```
echo xserver-xorg-lts-utopic hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections

echo xorg hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

After performing and update & upgrade is seemed to have worked. About to install the last version of the `fglrx` drivers from the AMD website and will report the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip kernel update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178324/how-to-skip-kernel-update)

Comment: More to read here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Comment: So that worked! Let's keep our fingers crossed that by end of life in April 2019 that AMD decides to update its drivers.