# Do kernel updates require every version in between?

Tags: kernel, updates

I am considering disabling auto-updates or [pinning the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/q/178324/30419) to a specific version. However I am concerned that when I later unpin the version, that all kernels in between the pinned version and the latest version will need to be downloaded and installed which would cause `/root` to [run out of disk space](https://askubuntu.com/q/57994/30419).

Does each kernel version need to be downloaded and installed or does `apt-get` know to only fetch the latest kernel?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Ubuntu will only download and install the most recent kernel

I have an Ubuntu computer that stays turned off for months. When I turn it on and let it update itself, it only downloads the latests kernel, and skips the ones in between.

You may want to run

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

After each updating kernels so that `/boot` has only two most recently installed kernels. This way, if the latest kernel misbehaves you can go back to the previously working kernel, and at the same time keep `/boot` from getting clogged up with old kernels.

Hope this helps

Comment: Since which version does `autoremove` clean up kernels?  It certainly didn't on Trusty, which requires manual removal.

Comment: @ChrisH: Last I checked, `autoremove` keeps the current kernel and one previous (and the currently-booted kernel), so you can recover if the new one fails to boot.  But it will remove kernels older than that.  See `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` and `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` which generates that.  (If you've done multiple updates that installed new kernels but never got around to booting them, do `autoremove` *after* rebooting to get down to 2 kernels installed, instead of 3)

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer: No**

**Longer answer:** I have some Ubuntu flavour systems (Lubuntu and Xubuntu), that I run rather seldom. When I update & upgrade them, they will often skip several kernel versions, and there are no problems. I usually run the following commands, and receive the current kernel version (of the same kernel series),

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

It is a good idea to run

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

after a new kernel is installed, so that `/boot` has only two most recently installed kernels. You can select the previous kernel from the grub menu, if there are problems with the new kernel.

Answer (score 7):

Pinning is usually used only when you have mixed repositories

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

I suggest you put the kernel on hold

[How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Either way, once you reverse the hold or pinning, apt will only download and update the most recent kernel skipping any and all kernels between.